# Can not escape slashes from postgres database

Tags: php, postgresql

Cannot escape slashes from my postgresql database.

[image]

I tried to use addslashes function but it doesn't work.

I need values to be as:
\d9\0f.. and so on

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please never provide any value / code chuck in an image. Always post them as text. Also, share with us what you've tried so far. Where exactly you have doubts?

Comment: *"I tried to use addslashes function but it doesn't work."* - What "doesn't work" about it?  The image implies pretty strongly that slashes were indeed added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the screenshot, you displayed the result in the terminal, but in the table itself the slashes are already escaped like this:

```
\\\\d9\\\\0f..
```

so to get the necessary format you just need to remove one escaped slash

```
str_replace("\\\\", "\\", $str)
```